Carousel - hide navigation elements?
My case:
should I have to hide navigation elements of carousel (like arrows or fors) when admin upload only one card to it? Or maybe I should display disabled arrows on the both sides?
I will be very grateful for any sources/resaerch about that, thanks a lot!

What would you say would be the benefit for the user to see the disabled elements on a static element that they can't interact with? I think it only carries the risk of confusing them, e.g. "Why is it disabled, did I not allow some cookies?".

Personally, I lean towards using actions for their intended role, mainly because seeing a certain action leads to certain assumptions. If a user sees arrows for a carousel, disabled or enabled, then they should automatically assume that at some point, they'll be able to use them. The arrows on a carousel are always there to control the pace of the auto-forwarding feature (See reference, MailChimp Article). So, if there isn't any auto-forwarding, why should the arrows be there.
I think it's best to leave them out for now and when you have an overflow and carousel animates, you then add the arrows to allow the user to checkout a slide they might have missed.
Reference: Carousel Design: Best Practices for UX - MailChimp Marketing
